# Progress bar on developer survey is broken

Tags: bug, survey, survey-2017

I don't know if this is the correct place to raise this problem, but I just took the annual developer survey.  It appears to me that the progress bar is broken:

[image]

Notice that it claims that I'm almost done, but the progress bar only says 51%.  I didn't take careful note of the last position of the bar, but I don't remember it going above 70% ever<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>This is circumstantial ... As I said, I didn't take not of the last position :-)</sup>

Comment: You're right.  I've voted to close.  I searched for "developer survey progress bar" and didn't get any results so I thought I might have a new bug to report.  Apparently not.