# Developer Survey Design, in desperate need of a progress bar

Tags: discussion, survey-2017

[image]

I am completing the DS and currently in question 29, unfortunately I do not know how many more questions are there, it will be a GREAT idea to add a progress bar. Am I the only one feeling the pain?

PS: [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341431/progress-bar-on-developer-survey-is-broken) at least shows a progress bar whereas now there isn't one.

Comment: We had a progress bar. Which was completely broken (we use Survey Monkey) - it wasn't properly accounting for the possibility of some questions being skipped depending on previous answers. This was way worse than not having a progress at all and is not something we (Stack Overflow) can fix.

Comment: Related: [Survey ends at 57%… intentional joke or actual bug?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341414/survey-ends-at-57-intentional-joke-or-actual-bug)

Comment: Awesome! Is like I will be answering that survey now!